# What is expected number of turns to play this children's game?

Tags: probability, game-theory

I'm playing this game with children and I'm ready to stab my eyes with an ice pick.
It seems like it never ends, but I know I expect it to end. What is my expected number of spins to remove all the fruit from the tree?

Goal: To remove 14 cherries from tree by executing one of following seven directions at random per turn.

```
 1. Remove 1 cherry.
 2. Remove 2 cherries.
 3. Remove 3 cherries.
 4. Remove 4 cherries.
 5. Return 1 cherry to tree.
 6. Return 2 cherries to tree.
 7. Return all your cherries to tree.
```

Once I realized I have a 1/7 chance each turn of playing this game in perpetuity, I started reaching for the kitchen drawer.

Comment: Suppose there are 2 cherries on the tree. Does the game end if you roll a 3 or a 4? (ie, if you're asked to remove more cherries than there are left.)

Comment: Yes, if there are two cherries, picking 2,3, or 4 cherries will end the game.

Comment: Also, if all 14 cherries are on the tree and you roll a 5, does the tree now have 15 cherries or does nothing happen?

Comment: In my solution below, I assume that nothing happens in this case.

Comment: Um, if there are children threatening you with ice picks, then the statistical properties of some game probably shouldn't be on top of your priority list.

Comment: @Henning: I think OP is the one planning on stabbing his own eyes out.

Comment: I independently got the same result as DSM got in the answer now deleted: $1077219654336/40719238081\approx26.4548087121169$. However, when I do the same for $10$ cherries, I get $1179248/80915\approx14.573910894148181$, slightly different from Nate's result.

Comment: @Henning, Now I'm laughing. I don't know which is worse, my grammar or my understanding of game theory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I actually spent some time about a year ago doing some computations for a variant of this game, sold as [Hi-Ho Cherry-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hi_Ho!_Cherry-O).  It's identical to your game, except with 10 cherries instead of 14. (I learned about it from a colleague with a 4-year-old daughter.)

The computation is a nice example of some simple Markov chain techniques, which produce linear equations of the sort in Brett Frankel's answer.  I considered the cases of 1 to 4 players, which are amenable to computer solution.

Another interesting feature is that since the players take turns, the first player has a slight advantage.

Here are the results I got for 10 cherries.  If you are really interested, I can try and reconstruct my code and run the 14 cherry case.

```
1 player game:

Expected length: 15.8019792994073 rounds

2 player game:

Expected number of rounds: 9.58554137805221
P(player 1 wins) = 0.518720469382215
P(player 2 wins) = 0.481279530617784
Expected number of turns = 18.6523622867222

3 player game:

Expected number of rounds: 7.49668096168849
P(player 1 wins) =  0.357756582790784
P(player 2 wins) =  0.332728455615310
P(player 3 wins) =  0.309514961593905
Expected number of turns: 21.4418012638686

4 player game:

Expected number of rounds: 6.44149249272987
P(player 1 wins) =  0.276928283784381
P(player 2 wins) =  0.258099951775544
P(player 3 wins) =  0.240610168544412
P(player 4 wins) =  0.224361595895655
Expected number of turns: 24.1783750474708
```

**Edit**: I should also mention some [previous work](http://www.math.byu.edu/~jeffh/mathematics/games/cherry/cherry.html) by Jeffrey Humpherys.

Comment: I get $1179248/80915\approx14.573910894148181$ for $10$ cherries, yet the same as DSM for $14$ cherries. Are you sure you used exactly the same rules (especially when there aren't enough cherries to remove or to return)?

Comment: @joriki: DSM's answer is now deleted, but I believe the rule I used is that when there aren't enough cherries, you add or remove as many as possible.  E.g. if you have only one cherry in your bucket and spin a 6, you return that one cherry to your tree.  Again, I unfortunately only saved pieces of my code, so I can't check it, but perhaps if I have some time in the near future I'll reconstruct it.

Comment: Nate E.: The game is Hi-Ho-Cherry-Oh. It seems like 14 cherries!! After I removed the ice-picks from my eyes, I recounted and there are just 10 cherries.

Comment: I've resolved the discrepancy between our results; see my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can solve via a series of 14 linear equations:
Let $E_n$ be the expected number of turns remaining until the game is over when there are currently $n$ cherries on the tree.
For example, $$E_1=\frac{4}{7}1+\frac{1}{7}(1+E_2)+\frac{1}{7}(1+E_3)+\frac{1}{7}(1+E_{14})$$

$$E_{14}=\frac{1}{7}(1+E_{13})+\frac{1}{7}(1+E_{12})+\frac{1}{7}(1+E_{11})+\frac{1}{7}(1+E_{10})+\frac{3}{7}(1+E_{14})$$

By the time you finish writing down all 14 equations and solving, the game may well be over. (Then again, I expect the answer will be quite large).

Answer (score 3):

I've found the reason for the discrepancy between Nate's answer and my results (which agree with DSM's). In [the version of the game that Nate linked to](http://www.math.byu.edu/~jeffh/mathematics/games/cherry/cherry.html), the dog and the bird both require you to return $2$ cherries to the tree, whereas in the present version 5. says one cherry and only 6. says two cherries. If I change my code to the linked version my result for the expected number of turns is in agreement with Nate's. For the present version, I get

$$\frac{1179248}{80915}\approx14.5739\;.$$